# Image Slider with "Responsive Width", "Fixed Height", "Center Aligned" and "Auto Rotate"

Tags: javascript, slider, responsive-slides

I need a full width (responsive) slider with fixed height and centered image ( the min width is 960px and people with a wider screens will see the rest of the image (the extra on the left and right)) and it needs to auto-rotate.

Now I got the html/css worked out, but my javascript is rubbish so i have no idea how to let the images slide. I've checked out a lot of Questions here but nothing seems to work. My image dimensions are 2300x350.

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#slider_container {
    width:100%;
    height:350px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.image {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    height: 350px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image img {   
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-1150px;
    margin-top:-175px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slider_container">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="images/header.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="images/header2.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="images/header3.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

With this code the pictures come out nice in the middle on every screen but
how do I let it slide and autorotate? I guess the first image just needs to be replaced by the second so a z-index change? or + or - the width of one picture?

Comment: Why don't you use a slider plugin? Flexslider would animate them and not more than 4 lines. And you dont even need to write css for that. **http://flexslider.woothemes.com/**

Comment: Im' trying flexslider right now, but i can't get the code to work full width :/ i tried this 
`$(function() {
      $('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 2300,
        height: 350
      });
    });`

but it does not work and you can't put width to 100%

Answer (score 1):

You need to only style the `img` tag if using **flexslider**. Try the fiddle link below. I have included four files for this.

- jQuery 1.9.1
- flexslider.css
- jquery.flexslider-min.js
- bg_direction_nav.png

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yxnhr/1/)**

Comment: thx ! but i got the result with jquery cycle plugin, easier then i thought!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this... http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-Full-Width-Image-Slider-Plugin-responsiveSlides/ it is full width and fixed height slider and auto rotate. Here you have options to styling according to your needs

```
$(function(){

    var p=$('#content').responsiveSlides({
        height:450,                     // slides conteiner height
        background:'#fff',              // background color and color of overlayer to fadeout on init
        autoStart:true,                 // boolean autostart
        startDelay:0,                   // start whit delay
        effectInterval:5000,            // time to swap photo
        effectTransition:1000,          // time effect
        pagination:[
            {
                active:true,            // activate pagination
                inner:true,             // pagination inside or aouside slides conteiner
                position:'B_R',         /* 
                                            pagination align:
                                                T_L = top left
                                                T_C = top center
                                                T_R = top right

                                                B_L = bottom left
                                                B_C = bottom center
                                                B_R = bottom right
                                        */
                margin:10,              // pagination margin
                dotStyle:'',            // dot pagination class style
                dotStyleHover:'',       // dot pagination class hover style
                dotStyleDisable:''      // dot pagination class disable style
            }
        ]
    });

});
```

For more modification please see jquery.responsiveSlides.js